# Когда нужно использовать умные указатели?

Tags: c++, qt

Пишу небольшую программу на Qt. Мне известно, что в Qt память освобождается через родительский класс. Но я решил освобождать память "вручную" по следующему примеру:

```
class Foo {
    Bar* bar;

    Foo() {
        bar = new Bar();
    }

    ~Foo() {
        delete bar;
    }
};
```

Оставляя тему освобождения памяти через родителей в стороне хотел бы узнать, когда в C++ нужно использовать умные указатели? Я действую по принципу: Сам насорил, сам убрал. Где насорил, там убрал. То, что я делаю, правильно? Может есть какие-то правила о том, когда нужно использовать умные указатели?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: В нормальном прикладном кода на C++ не должно быть вызовов `new` и `delete`. Если вам нужно выделить один объект, берите умный указатель, если несколько, берите вектор. Ваш пример, кстати, портит память после копирования объекта. Когда вы исправите этот и другие недостатки, получится плохо написанная половина умного указателя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если оставлять в стороне вопрос системы родителей Qt, то использовать умные указатели следует всегда.

Разберем чуть подробнее ваш пример:

```
std::vector <Foo> foos;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Foo foo;
    // do stuff with foo
    foos.push_back(foo);
}
```

После этого ваш код свалится с ошибкой. Добрый компилятор сам сгенерировал вам конструктор копирования, только он не в курсе, что указатель чем-то владеет, поэтому на выходе из скоупа объект `foo` будет удален, а указатель, который лежал внутри и который все еще используется в объекте, помещенном в вектор, теперь смотрит на удаленные данные.

Допустим мы напишем ручками конструктор копирования, это не так и сложно для нашего класса. Теперь по правилам компилятор не сможет сгенерировать для класса конструктор перемещения, а нам возможно хотелось бы сделать `foos.push_back(std::move(foo));` чтобы не дергать лишних копирований. Придется написать еще и конструктор перемещения, не забыв аккуратно занулить неиспользуемые указатели в тех местах, откуда перемещены ресурсы. И про `noexcept` желательно не забыть, хотя современные IDE обычно подскажут.

Теперь представим себе что нужно расширить класс еще одним полем. Надо пройтись по всем конструкторам и ассайнментам и добавить везде корректное поведение, нигде ничего не забыв.

А всего-то можно было сделать ваш `bar` или `std::unique_ptr` или `std::shared_ptr` в зависимости от нужного поведения и все остальное компилятор сделает за вас.

Самый лучший код - код, который не написан, в нем нет багов. Пусть компилятор делает грязную работу за вас.

Answer (score 3):

Я считаю, что умные указатели нужно использовать тогда, когда это возможно. Если вы пишите что-либо, что требует освобождения памяти каким-то "магическим" способом и деструктором умного указателя здесь не обойтись - не используйте его. Но так ли вам вообще нужен умный указатель? В STL как и в Qt есть QVector/vector, QList/list и т.д. Лучше избавляться от ручного выделения/освобождения, так как вы можете забыть про delete/delete[] и у вас появится утечка памяти. В векторе такого не будет. Я не говорю, что нужно вычеркнуть delete/new из C++ и забыть как страшный сон - иногда вам придётся прибегать к их использованию, и вот тогда умный указатель вам и поможет.